# javascript is not updating html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to change my page while processing something but my page is only updated at the end of the process.
I created this simple code to show the problem.
When I press the button, it should remove the button from the page and show a message while processing the wait function. But it is not. It only hides the button at the end of the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getmybutton() {
            $('#mybutton').remove();
            $('#end').append('<p>button should be gone now!</p>' );
            wait(2000);
            $('#end').append('<h1>end of my test</h1>');
        }

        function wait(ms) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var end = start;
            while (end < start + ms) {
                end = new Date().getTime();
            }
        }
    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h1>test
        </h1>
        <button id='mybutton' onclick="getmybutton()" type="submit">press my button</button>
        <div id="end">
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You are blocking the render engine of the browser. Use `setTimeout()`

Comment: javascript is for all intents and purposes 'single threaded' and will execute your code until it finds a suitable gap in which to update the rendering. `setTimeout` is asynchronous, ie it doesn't hold up the thread. However, your while loop does hold up the thread.

Comment: Yes, setTimeout() solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `setTimeout()` in this situation.

Your implementation will hold up the current thread, `setTimeout` will wait to execute your `endOfTest` after the time interval has passed in a seperate thread.

The first parameter is the function you want to execute, and the second parameter is the time in `ms` in which it will execute the function after that time has `elapsed`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getmybutton() {
            $('#mybutton').remove();
            $('#end').append('<p>button should be gone now!</p>' );

                      //Function, Time
            setTimeout(endOfTest, 2000);
        }

        function endOfTest() {
          $('#end').append('<h1>end of my test</h1>');
        }
    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h1>test
        </h1>
        <button id='mybutton' onclick="getmybutton()" type="submit">press my button</button>
        <div id="end">
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```